# Need to add a configuration file twice

Tags: php

This problem has been worrying me since 2 weeks.

Code :-

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../dbconnector.php';

function getRandUsername()
{
    include '../dbconnector.php';
    $u = rand(0,99999);
    //check if the number exists in the database already
    $query="SELECT * from admin where username = '" . $u . "'";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "Username Exists";
        getRandUsername();
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username Does not exist";
    }
}

getRandUsername();

?>
```

**Problem** :- The problem is, that I need to include this **dbconnector.php** file twice. If I don't include it within the function parentheses, it would throw an error. While if the file is include in the function block, everything works fine.

What's wrong in here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `include_once`?

Comment: Sidenote: `mt_rand()` is faster than `rand()`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this function.
Using it now.

Comment: You're welcome. You also could probably use MySQL's built-in [`RAND()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-rand-function.htm) function, instead of all that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
require_once '../dbconnector.php';

function getRandUsername() {
    global $db;    // where I'm assuming that $db is defined in the external file
```